# Get a list of distinct first letters of a name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Environment: Rails 3.2.13 with SQLite in development and PostgreSQL in production

Using Active Record, I'm trying to get a list of unique first letters from all first names in the DB. For example, if I have names (Alex, Billy, Bob, Dave, Jack, James, Jen, Sam, Steve, Stewart, Victor) I'm trying to get the letters (A,B,D,J,S,V) from the DB.

I've been able to go into the Rails DB Console and query SQLite and get what I want using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(last_name,1,1) FROM people ORDER BY last_name;
```

But haven't been able to get it to work within Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use, for instance

```
User.all.map{|u| u.name[0]}.uniq
```

but this is in memory. If you need to do it in SQL, you can use [find_by_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class)